# Reliable way to override javascript globals

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to mock the date on a CefSharp browser by injecting [MockDate](https://github.com/boblauer/MockDate) and setting it to some fixed date before every other script runs. Every `window` object, on any frame, at any time, should only have access to the mocked date, so the ideal would be to internally redefine the JavaScript `Date` object, but I don't think CefSharp or probably even Chromium has this option. I'm also going to mock some other functions like `setTimeout` and `Math.rand`, to prevent the browser from having any side effects (this is part of a larger project whose aim is to be able to record/replay browsing activity), so messing with OS's time wouldn't solve it.

I considered using [RegisterJsObject](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_RegisterJsObject.htm) since it can actually overwrite existing globals, but I don't think there is a way to pass a JavaScript constructor.

What I've tried so far is to handle the [FrameLoadStart](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadStart.htm) event:

```
private static string Inject = File.ReadAllText("Inject.js");

private void ChromeBrowser_FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
{
    e.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(Inject);
}
```

Where "Inject.js" contains the mock date code. But I've noticed that, randomly, sometimes it'll work and sometimes it won't. I guess because the function is async and the javascript context sometimes haven't been created, since according to the documentations you shouldn't run scripts here. The documentation recommends handling [OnContextCreated](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRenderProcessMessageHandler_OnContextCreated.htm) instead, but it only runs for the main frame, which wouldn't let me inject the code on any iframe. So I wonder if I have any alternative.

Comment: If you need that level of control then you might be better off using CefGlue or ChromiumFx

Comment: @amaitland How hard would it be for me to modify CefSharp to fire `OnContextCreated` for every frame? Can you point me to to the right direction?

Comment: Just search the source for oncontextcreated, will only take you a few minutes to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else need this, the solution was to modify the actual C++ CefSharp code by adding a line to the end of `CefAppUnmanagedWrapper::OnContextCreated`:

```
frame->ExecuteJavaScript(CodeToInject, "something://something", 1);
```

This won't work if injected on the C# side, I believe because these calls are async so you may be injecting it too late, after scripts on the page have already run.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit HTML entry points then you can just add `window.Date = MockDate` before any other scripts. For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="mockdate.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Date = MockDate
</script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the idea is you can tune script loading order in your HTML. It can be done in any browser.

If you can not or do not want to edit HTML then it's much trickier. You could use [CefLoadHandler](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/2f6475c0d89c8b94458b6f7a1146724dbccde09f/include/cef_load_handler.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) in CEF C++ or its alternative in CefSharp.

UPD
Actually i'm not sure about CefLoadHandler. The reliable way would be to implement your own [CefRenderProcessHandler](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/2f6475c0d89c8b94458b6f7a1146724dbccde09f/include/cef_render_process_handler.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) But you already mentioned it. If it doesn't work then it's a bug in CefSharp or CEF C++ itself. In that case it would be better to write about it on http://magpcss.org/ceforum/